# LongMessage: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration. ShortMessage: Invalid Configuration ErrorCode: 10501

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce

I am getting this error, can anybody help me. May be I am missing out some steps:

LongMessage: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration. ShortMessage: Invalid Configuration ErrorCode: 10501

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Can you post the call that is getting this response?

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable "Paypal Payment Pro" or "Paypal Payment advance" service to enable credit card payment on you website.

Paypal Payment advance

```
$30 per month.
Customers pay (with CC) without ever leaving your website
```

Paypal Payment Pro

```
$5 per month
Customers pay (with CC) without ever leaving your website
Accept credit cards via phone, fax, and mail
Design and host your own checkout pages for full control
```

To enable above service you need to call paypal support. For more information please refer to below link.

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products

Answer (score 3):

Error 10501 can occur if using DoDirectPayment API but you do not have PayPal Payments Pro on your account.

If you have Payments Pro on your account but still getting this error, it could be an account setup issue; in that case contact customer support to further investigate.